# Import two CSV, add specific columns from one CSV and import changes to new CSV (C#)

Tags: c#, csv

i have to import 2 CSV's.

**CSV 1 [49]:** Including about 50 tab seperated colums.
**CSV 2:[2]** Inlcudes 3 Columns which should be replaced on the [3] [6] and [11] place of my first csv.

So heres what i do:

1) Importing the csv and split into a array.

```
string employeedatabase = "MYPATH";


List<String> status = new List<String>();

StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
string line = file2.ReadLine();
while ((line = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] ud = line.Split('\t');
    status.Add(ud[0]);

}

String[] ud_status = status.ToArray();
```

PROBLEM 1: i have about 50 colums to handle, ud_status is just the first, so do i need 50 Lists and 50 String arrays?

2) Importing the second csv and split into a array.

```
List<String> vorname = new List<String>();
List<String> nachname = new List<String>();
List<String> username = new List<String>();

StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(employeedatabase);
string line3 = file.ReadLine();
while ((line3 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] data = line3.Split(';');
    vorname.Add(data[0]);
    nachname.Add(data[1]);
    username.Add(data[2]);
}

String[] db_vorname = vorname.ToArray();
String[] db_nachname = nachname.ToArray();
String[] db_username = username.ToArray();
```

PROBLEM 2: After loading these two csv's i dont know how to combine them, and change to columns as mentioned above ..

somethine like this?

```
mynewArray = ud_status + "/t" + ud_xy[..n] + "/t" + changed_colum + ud_xy[..n];
```

save "mynewarray" into tablulator seperated csv with encoding "utf-8".

Comment: This is confusing. What does the "[43]" and "[2]" represent? Do they contain different data? And if the data is different, you haven't explained how you want to combine them.

Comment: Well, my first csv got about 50 tab seperated colums, so the "43" "2" or "xy" just a placeholder, shorty: 1. import a 50 column csv 2. import a 3 column csv. 3. change three colums of the first csv, for example on the "2" "43" and "46" column with the data of my second csv. 4. put all back together with three changed colums and export the csv.  About the data: On both csv there are just Strings, additional info: the csv have the same amount of lines.

Comment: Do these CSVs have a relation?  For instance, is the unique row identifier of one stored in a column in the other?

Comment: readability hint: would be helpful to translate German variable names to English

Comment: csv1: status | userid | name  | surename ... [+48 more]   ### csv2: userid | name | sure (just this 3), replace the userid,name,surname from csv2 to csv1.

Answer (score 0):

To read the file into a meaningful format, you should set up a class that defines the format of your CSV:

```
public class CsvRow
{
    public string vorname { get; set; }
    public string nachname { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public CsvRow (string[] data)
    {
         vorname = data[0];
         nachname = data[1];
         username = data[2];
    }
}
```

Then populate a list of this:

```
List<CsvRow> rows = new List<CsvRow>();

StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(employeedatabase);
string line3 = file.ReadLine();
while ((line3 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    rows.Add(new CsvRow(line3.Split(';'));
}
```

Similarly format your other CSV and include unused properties for the new fields. Once you have loaded both, you can populate the new properties from this list in a loop, matching the records by whatever common field the CSVs hopefully share. Then finally output the resulting data to a new CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not to use `string` arrays to do this. That will just drive you crazy.  It's better to use the `System.Data.DataTable` object.

I didn't get a chance to test the LINQ lambda expression at the end of this (or really any of it, I wrote this on a break), but it should get you on the right track.

```
using (var ds = new System.Data.DataSet("My Data"))
        {
            ds.Tables.Add("File0");
            ds.Tables.Add("File1");
            string[] line;
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("FirstFile"))
            {                       
                //first we get columns for table 0                    
                foreach (string s in reader.ReadLine().Split('\t'))
                    ds.Tables["File0"].Columns.Add(s);
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine().Split('\t')) != null)
                {
                    //and now the rest of the data. 
                    var r = ds.Tables["File0"].NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= line.Length; i++)
                    {
                        r[i] = line[i];
                    }
                    ds.Tables["File0"].Rows.Add(r);
                }                   
            }
            //we could probably do these in a loop or a second method,
            //but you may want subtle differences, so for now we just do it the same way 
            //for file1
            using (var reader2 = new System.IO.StreamReader("SecondFile"))
            {
                foreach (string s in reader2.ReadLine().Split('\t'))
                    ds.Tables["File1"].Columns.Add(s);
                while ((line = reader2.ReadLine().Split('\t')) != null)
                {
                    //and now the rest of the data. 
                    var r = ds.Tables["File1"].NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= line.Length; i++)
                    {
                        r[i] = line[i];
                    }
                    ds.Tables["File1"].Rows.Add(r);
                }
            }
            //you now have these in functioning datatables. Because we named columns, 
            //you can call them by name specifically, or by index, to replace in the first datatable. 
            string[] columnsToReplace = new string[] { "firstColumnName", "SecondColumnName", "ThirdColumnName" };
            for(int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //you didn't give a sign of any relation between the two tables
                //so this is just by row, and assumes the row count is equivalent.
                //This is also not advised. 
                //if there is a key these sets of data share
                //you should join on them instead. 
                foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray)
                {
                    dr[3] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][columnsToReplace[0]];
                    dr[6] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][columnsToReplace[1]];
                    dr[11] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][columnsToReplace[2]];
                }
            }
            //ds.Tables[0] now has the output you want.  
            string output = String.Empty;
            foreach (var s in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
               output = String.Concat(output, s ,"\t");
            output = String.Concat(output, Environment.NewLine); // columns ready, now the rows. 
            foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
               output = string.Concat(output, r.ItemArray.SelectMany(t => (t.ToString() + "\t")), Environment.NewLine);
            if(System.IO.File.Exists("MYPATH"))
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("MYPATH")) //or a variable instead of string literal
                {                  
                    file.Write(output);
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source file helper library, you can do the merge of CSV files as below. Assumed the 2 CSV file contains same number of lines.

```
string CSV1 = @"Id  Name    City
1   Tom New York
2   Mark    FairFax";

string CSV2 = @"Id  City
1   Las Vegas
2   Dallas";

dynamic rec1 = null;
dynamic rec2 = null;
StringBuilder csv3 = new StringBuilder();
using (var csvOut = new ChoCSVWriter(new StringWriter(csv3))
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    .WithDelimiter("\t")
    )
{
    using (var csv1 = new ChoCSVReader(new StringReader(CSV1))
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        .WithDelimiter("\t")
        )
    {
        using (var csv2 = new ChoCSVReader(new StringReader(CSV2))
            .WithFirstLineHeader()
            .WithDelimiter("\t")
            )
        {
            while ((rec1 = csv1.Read()) != null && (rec2 = csv2.Read()) != null)
            {
                rec1.City = rec2.City;
                csvOut.Write(rec1);
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(csv3.ToString());
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.